# Simple escaped http request via CMD or Browser from within a batch

Tags: batch-file, httprequest, encode

I need to automate opening a program, then making a simple HTTP request from a batch file.

I can't install CURL or WGet or any other handler. If possible I'd like to make the request in CMD, but a normal browser would also work.

The below batch file is what I have...

```
echo

start "" "C:\Program Files\SpacialAudio\SimpleCast\SimpleCast.exe"

ping localhost -n 5 > nul  

Start http://localhost:8181/?artist=myartist&title=mytitle&songtype=S&duration=240000
```

Question 1: Do I have to use the default browser?

Question 2: The above batch minces up the url, so how do I escape it correctly?

The browser ends up requesting

```
http://localhost:8181/?artist=myartist
```

Even if I encode the URL first

```
http://localhost:8181/?artist=myartist&amp;title=mytitle&amp;songtype=S&amp;duration=240000
```

I get the same result

Answer (score 1):

double quote the URL.

```
start "" "http://blah.blah.com&text"
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for the browser option. I won't mark it as answered just yet in case someone can suggest an alternative to using the browser. If at all possible.